# Creating one JSON object by reading all the .txt files from a directory

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch, text-files, data-analysis

I am using the 20twenty news groups dataset from scikitlearn. And there are 20 .txt files and some of them have the structure like below - with newgroup name, docID, From, Subject. I want to read all the files (20) from the directory to convert it to a json object or CSV to input this to elastic search for indexing.

Each new article is starting with "Newsgroup", document_id etc.. Below is one sample.

```
Newsgroup: sci.space
document_id: 59497
From: et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)
Subject: Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise

In article <C4KvJF.4qo@well.sf.ca.us> metares@well.sf.ca.us (Tom Van Flandern) writes:
>crb7q@kelvin.seas.Virginia.EDU (Cameron Randale Bass) writes:
>> Bruce.Scott@launchpad.unc.edu (Bruce Scott) writes:
>>> "Existence" is undefined unless it is synonymous with "observable" in
>>> physics.
>> [crb] Dong ....  Dong ....  Dong ....  Do I hear the death-knell of
>> string theory?
>
>     I agree.  You can add "dark matter" and quarks and a lot of other
>unobservable, purely theoretical constructs in physics to that list,
>including the omni-present "black holes."
>
>     Will Bruce argue that their existence can be inferred from theory
>alone?  Then what about my original criticism, when I said "Curvature
>can only exist relative to something non-curved"?  Bruce replied:
>"'Existence' is undefined unless it is synonymous with 'observable' in
>physics.  We cannot observe more than the four dimensions we know about."
>At the moment I don't see a way to defend that statement and the
>existence of these unobservable phenomena simultaneously.  -|Tom|-

"I hold that space cannot be curved, for the simple reason that it can have
no properties."
"Of properties we can only speak when dealing with matter filling the
space. To say that in the presence of large bodies space becomes curved,
is equivalent to stating that something can act upon nothing. I,
for one, refuse to subscribe to such a view." - Nikola Tesla

----
 ET  "Tesla was 100 years ahead of his time. Perhaps now his time comes."
----

Newsgroup: comp.os.ms-windows.misc
document_id: 10002
Subject: Re: Win31 & doublespace
From: edowdy@vax1.umkc.edu

In article <4363@hpwala.wal.hp.com>, chrisa@hpwarr.hp.com ( Chris Almy) writes:
> 
>   Doublespace, although I do not trust it for my hard disks, sounds
>   great for floppies. The thouoght of having to mount the disk
>   is anoying but something I can deal with. The problem arises 
>   when under windows. Is there a way to mount and unmount while
>   under windows or is this part of the upgrades soon to be 
>   available from other vendors?
```

Each .txt file contains almost 1000 documents with Newsgroup, document_id, From , Subject. So the second article again starts with "Newgroup..."

I am doing the below to read the files from directory, but not sure how to convert and capture the above 4 fields to a json/csv.

```
files = glob.glob(path + '\\*.txt')
# iterate over the list getting each file 
for fle in files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
   with open(fle) as f:
     text = f.read()
```

Comment: Which fields? Newsgroup, document_id, From, Subject?

Comment: @andreis11 yes. Separate columns if it is a CSV for all 4 of them (Newsgroup, document_id, From, Subject)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
    import functools
    import operator

    targeted_fields = [ 'Newsgroup', 'document_id', 'From', 'Subject' ]

    _article_list = []
    _final_dict_list = []

    files = glob.glob(path + '\\*.txt')
    # iterate over the list getting each file 
    for fle in files:
      _tmp_subject_list = []
      _tmp_header_list = []
      with open(fle) as f:
        data = [x.strip("\n").split(':',1) for x in f.readlines()]
        for each in data:      
          if each[0] == targeted_fields[0]:
            _article_list.append( [ *_tmp_header_list, functools.reduce(operator.concat, _tmp_subject_list, []) ] )
            _tmp_subject_list = []
            _tmp_header_list = [each]

          elif each[0] in targeted_fields[1:3]:
            _tmp_header_list.append(each)

          else:
            _tmp_subject_list.append(each)

          if data.index(each) == len(data)-1:
            _article_list.append( [ *_tmp_header_list, functools.reduce(operator.concat, _tmp_subject_list, []) ] )

    _article_list = [ x for x in _article_list if len(x)>1 ]    # Removing empty lines

    for x in _article_list:
      _final_dict_list.append( { y[0] : ' '.join(y[1:]) for y in x} )
```

---

The following approach works even if each file contains more articles:

```
targeted_fields = [ 'Newsgroup', 'document_id', 'From', 'Subject' ]

_final_list = []

files = glob.glob(path + '\\*.txt')
# iterate over the list getting each file 
for fle in files:

  with open(fle) as f:
    data = [x.split(':',1) for x in f.readlines()]
    _temp_list = []
    for each in data:
      if each != '' and each[0] in targeted_fields:
        _temp_list.append(each)
      if len(_temp_list) // len(targeted_fields):
        _final_list.append({x[0]:x[1].strip("\n") for x in _temp_list})
        _temp_list = []
```

The `_final_list` will be a list of dictionaries, sample format(using 2 articles in 2 files, hence 4 results):

```
[ { 'From': ' et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)',
    'Newsgroup': ' sci.space',
    'Subject': ' Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization '
               '& Cosmic Noise',
    'document_id': ' 59497'},
  { 'From': ' et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)2',
    'Newsgroup': ' sci.space2',
    'Subject': ' Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization '
               '& Cosmic Noise2',
    'document_id': ' 594972'},
  { 'From': ' et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)',
    'Newsgroup': ' sci.space',
    'Subject': ' Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization '
               '& Cosmic Noise',
    'document_id': ' 59497'},
  { 'From': ' et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)2',
    'Newsgroup': ' sci.space2',
    'Subject': ' Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization '
               '& Cosmic Noise2',
    'document_id': ' 594972'}]
```

To transform the final results to json:

```
import json

data = json.dumps(_final_list)
```

Json output:

```
[{"Newsgroup": " sci.space", "document_id": " 59497", "From": " et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)", "Subject": " Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise"}, {"Newsgroup": " sci.space2", "document_id": " 594972", "From": " et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)2", "Subject": " Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise2"}, {"Newsgroup": " sci.space", "document_id": " 59497", "From": " et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)", "Subject": " Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise"}, {"Newsgroup": " sci.space2", "document_id": " 594972", "From": " et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)2", "Subject": " Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise2"}]
```

To transform to csv:

```
keys = _final_list[0].keys()
with open('people.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(_final_list)
```

Csv output:

```
Newsgroup,document_id,From,Subject
 sci.space, 59497, et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)," Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise"
 sci.space2, 594972, et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)2," Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise2"
 sci.space, 59497, et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)," Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise"
 sci.space2, 594972, et@teal.csn.org (Eric H. Taylor)2," Re: Gravity waves, was: Predicting gravity wave quantization & Cosmic Noise2"
```

Comment: How do I capture all the text that follows after subject line as "subject" itself?

Comment: "subject" itself ? What do you mean? Could you use an example? Or do you mean the text from `In article..` until the end?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear - I meant can we capture the text after "subject:"  (From the text example - text starting from  `"Re: Gravity waves ............ Perhaps now his time comes."` under "subject" key in JSON or column in CSV.

Comment: Ah, so the key "Subject" to contain basically the rest of the document(Re -> end of file? To answer this, does each file contain one article only ? (one article that starts with Newsgroup, document_id, From , Subject:)

Comment: Each .txt file contains almost 1000 documents with Newsgroup, document_id, From , Subject. So the second article again starts with "Newgroup..." (Edited and updated the sample data in the question, pls check above if that helps